# Location of Fuel Pump relay on '07 TSX

Tags: fuel-system, relay, acura, pump, tsx

I'm having frequent hard starting issues & think the problem is the fuel pump relay. However, I have no idea where this is located, presumably under the dash somewhere.
Anybody?

Comment: The first place I would check is the fuse and relay box in the engine compartment. The underside of the cover should have a diagram on it.

Comment: This parts diagram suggests it may be in the interior fuse box behind the left kick panel (just above the hood release if your car is left-hand drive). https://estore.honda.com/acura/parts/view-acura-parts-catalog-detail.asp?m=2007-tsx-4-tsx-5at&sn=&b=B++1310&dl=

Answer (score 1):

Jim Perris comment is correct; Here's the location picture I found in my software...

[image: 07 Acura TSX Main 1 Main 2 (Fuel Pump) Relay Locations]